# SQL query taking long time in excel

Tags: sql, excel

I am using an excel file that imports data into a table using a SQL query. 
First of all, recently it started taking ages to run and crashes quite often.

Secondly. On regular basis I get the following errors popping up:
[image]

Followed by:
[image]

Now My sql knowledge is extremely limited but I did find the connection string and Command text in Excel.

Connection string:
    DSN=RM Statistics;Description=*XXX* Database;UID=*XXX*;Trusted_Connection=Yes;APP=Microsoft Office 2013;WSID=*XXX*;DATABASE=rmstatistics

The Command string is basically a simple SELECT command to extract information excluding on some specific filters.

Any clues on what might cause the extremely long loading times (think like 1 hour), why excel crashes while running it and what the error messages mean??

Comment: Most likely network connection is poor (cabling problem, unstable wifi) - both messages indicate problem with reading data, second message specifically mentions network too.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to take a stab at this. I would look at three things:

1.Sufficient SQL processing power. Does this query take just as long when you execute it directly on your sql server instance?

2.Sufficient Network throughput. Is your network latency sufficient to keep the connection from timing out?

3.Do you have a Firewall?

You might also want to take a look at this.
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20961170/Getting-Microsoft-ODBC-SQL-Server-Driver-DBNETLIB-ConnectionRead-recv-errors.html

Hope this helps.